Book about a girl who lives in a world with genetically-modified humans and runs into a girl who looks exactly like her
I recall reading a story about a young teen girl who lives in a world with genetically-modified humans and non-modified humans. On a school trip (rock climbing/hiking?), she runs into a girl who looks exactly like her but is 'non-modified'. I also recall they have a female leader who is reborn as a clone to continue her reign.
I'm pretty sure this book is not Replica by Lauren Oliver. Any ideas?

In roughly which year did you read this? And do you recall anything about the cover?

This is Star Split by Kathryn Lasky.

During the summer, Darci goes to rock climbing camp, and meets a girl identical to herself, Vivian. As Darci was born first, Vivian must be her "copy". The two girls are terrified: in their society, unauthorized cloning is the worst crime, punished with death for the perpetrators and all the cloned people. Vivian and Darci know that they must keep their meeting a secret, or they could be sentenced to death together with their parents.



That’s the one! My husband and I were talking about human genetic engineering last night and it triggered this memory. All google searches led to Replica but I knew that wasn’t it. I just remembered it contributed to thoughts about genetic engineering even if it wasn’t an amazing story. Thank you.

@JenniferBeauchesne - You're very welcome :-)
